Angular :enter and :leave transitions not working (v. 18.0.5)
I am trying to create an :enter and :leave fade-in and fade-out transition for an HTML element, but it doesn't seem to work. Or in some cases works unexpectedly... This is the HTML in my template:
<li (click)="toggleDot()">
  @if (showDot) {
    <div @fadeInOut class="dot"></div>
  }
</li>

My .ts document looks like this:
animations: [
  trigger('fadeInOut', [
    transition(':enter', [
      style({ opacity: '0' }),
      animate('1s ease-in', style({ opacity: '1' })),
    ]),
    transition(':leave', [
      style({ opacity: '1' }),
      animate('1s ease-in', style({ opacity: '0' })),
    ]),
  ]),
],

In the class body I have a variable and a function to toggle it:
  showDot = true

  toggleDot() {
    this.showDot = !this.showDot
  }

I also did not forget to import provideAnimationsAsync in the app.config.ts file. Now, what exactly is going wrong? Because no transition or animation plays at all
I also tried importing the basic provideAnimations module, but this resulted in some weird behaviour where no transition happens at the beginning (after loading the page), but after 3-4 times triggering the transition it actually starts working (you can guess this is not optimal).
I also tried using *ngIf with CommonModule but it did not result in anything.
Another thing I can suspect is maybe some of the CSS interferes with it, but I don't have anything special there, so it shouldn't be at fault either, right?
While writing this question I've found a StackBlitz about :enter and :leave where my code seems to work, so maybe it is a setup error somewhere in my project?

try inspect element and check which is the problematic CSS
